# Arraylist with multiple objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I am supposed to include both a string and integer in an arraylist. So I made a separate class with both types of objects and used an arraylist on it but it results in errors.

Class:

```
public class Data {


private String name;
private int age;
Data(String n,int a)
{
    name = n;
    age = a;
}
public String GetName()
{
    return(name);
}
public void SetName(String n)
{
    name = n;
}
public int GetAge()
{
    return(age);
}
public void SetAge(int a)
{
    age = a;
}
public void Print()
{
    System.out.print(("("+GetName()));
    System.out.print(",");
    System.out.print(GetAge());
    System.out.print(") ");
}

}
```

Another class with Arraylist:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CSLab {


 ArrayList<Data> arlist = new ArrayList<Data>();

 arlist.add(new Data("Mark", 31));
 arlist.add(new Data("Joe", 13));
 arlist.add(new Data("Rob", 32));
 }
```

I don't think I have to include a *main* since it still results in the same errors regardless of its inclusion or not.

}

Comment: You most definitely do need a main.

Comment: (1) Show us the error messages you're getting. (2) Yes, you need a `main` function. (3) Are you sure you need a `Data` class? Tell us your assignment exactly, this may not be the right approach.

Comment: Yes I tried adding a main, silly mistake. It works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what error you got, but yes, you need a main; you can't just have code just in the middle of a class like that:

```
public class CS1702_lab5 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Data> arlist = new ArrayList<Data>();

  arlist.add(new Data("Mark", 31));
  arlist.add(new Data("Joe", 13));
  arlist.add(new Data("Rob", 32));
 }
}
```

Hopefully this addresses the error you actually got.  If it's a different error, post that error and we can deal with that.

Comment: Oh yes I did need a main. Thanks